# Taking point value back from operation

Tags: c#

I have to make a program in C# Traveling Salesman Problem. My application probably works properly. But the thing is I added every distances from point to point into one unique value inside of double array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lengths.Length; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < lengths.Length / n - 1; j++)
    {
        if (n >= 1)
        {
            double dX = p[n - n].X - p[1].X;
            double dY = p[n - n].Y - p[1].Y;
            double Wynik = Math.Sqrt((dX * dX + dY * dY));
            lengths[i] += Wynik;
        }
        else if (n >= 2)
        {
            double dX = p[n - n + 1].X - p[2].X;
            double dY = p[n - n + 1].Y - p[2].Y;
            double Wynik = Math.Sqrt((dX * dX + dY * dY));
            lengths[i] += Wynik;
        }
        else if (n >= 3)
        {
            double dX = p[n - n + 2].X - p[3].X;
            double dY = p[n - n + 2].Y - p[3].Y;
            double Wynik = Math.Sqrt((dX * dX + dY * dY));
            lengths[i] += Wynik;
        }
    }
}
```

And if I for example run the application it obviously calc the best possible way and draw every point I ask for, but I have no clue now how can I take back those Point(x,y) from the best possible way to draw lines on my pictureBox. 
[image: Here's how it looks like:]

Comment: A small correction to code: p[n-n] sort of means p[0] and p[n-n+1] means p[1]..

Comment: @Gauravsa Yea thank you bro :D as u can also notice there is no usage of "j". My question was If i Count distance beetween point A and point B and make it + into value of tab[i] can i retake data from this tab as X and Y of those points? In Traveling Salesman Problem there are so many possibilities :/

Comment: I think its better to have a class like Connection which have two points (from, two) and the distance. Point is gonna be another class with variable x, y. That way, your life is gonna be easy. You can then create a list and put "connection"s to the list. Its a bit of work from current code.

Comment: Guys i resolved my problem 3 years ago, haven't been posted anything on stack. If anyone need files i think i can search for them and upload to GitHub. Just let me know.